# Is it possible to consistently integrate Kontact in gnome?

Tags: gnome, kde

For many reasons I like Kontact much beter as PIM application vs Evolution. 
But I can't find any help on how to integrate the different parts into the gnome environment.

- Kmail as default mailer (that's possible) and use the indicator applet
- Tomboy or Basket to be used as replacement for knotes. At least sync.
- Kadrressbook to replace gnome adressbook ...
- Kcalendar replace calendar
- ...

Is this possible by any means? 
(and if it is, how?)

thx, piedro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that the answer is probably no. Kwallet works in GNOME with KDE applications and GNOME-keyring works in KDE with GNOME applications because in a hybrid system both KDE and GNOME supports are working. If you shut off that support then the application won't work.

You would have to rewrite code to do what you want and since we are talking two distinct toolkits, you are probably snookered.

Answer (score 1):

I have never had much success in making KDE apps look integrated into the GNOME desktop. The problem is that the desktop environments use different toolkits (KDE uses Qt; GNOME uses GTK). Each toolkit has its own quirks.

I'm afraid the answer is probably no.

Comment: thx for your answer. But I#m not talking about the looks. The look of all the KDE applications I run within gnome is near to perfect! Most of them undistinguishable from the gnome ones. 
 
I'm talking about funcionality: Get Tracker to search & index mails from kmail and notes in knotes, feeds from akregator e.g. 

Store passwords in gnome keyring or use keepassx to use kwallet & gnome-keyring at the same time ... stuff like this ... 

thx anyway, p.

Comment: @piedro some of that will depend on future work - there is work on a compatible, cross-desktop keyring API, but it is not yet deployed.  Once that is done, that corner should be easier.  not sure on Tracker et al.

Comment: thx Michael! Is there any link for status and/or information on these efforts?